# How to remove additional number appear in x-axis Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, column-chart

How to remove additional numbers appear in x-axis as (x-axis labels) while I enabled scrolling.
[Code Sample: jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/3782/)

**JS Code:**

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type:'column'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
    max: 8
},


scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
}]
});
```

**Resultant Image:**

[image]

**Note:** Please don't ask to change the max value to 3, i.e., max:3

Comment: Did you try: `categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','','','','',]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use tickPositions array for setting the positions of your ticks:

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
    max: 8,
    tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 3]
  },
```

Here you can find an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/3783/

Another idea is to use labels formatter and return empty string if you don't have category string on your label:

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
    max: 8,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return typeof this.value !== 'number' ? this.value : ''
      }
    }
  },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/3785/

Another idea is to fill your categories array with empty strings, just like Raghuveer suggested:

http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/3786/

Comment: Your 2nd solution suits me.